# react-dnd: dragging on overflowed parent

Tags: reactjs, draggable, scheduler, react-dnd

I am using [react-big-scheduler](https://github.com/StephenChou1017/react-big-scheduler) library to manage events .
When you drag and drop an event to a date that is outside the dates that are showen within the view it does not drop on the right date.
so lets say i select quarter and I drag an event from 1/1/2019 to 1/3/2019 so that is in the same quarter but the scrollbar has to scroll for it when i drag it to that date and drop it, it is placed on a whole diffrent date.

An example of this can be seen at https://stephenchou1017.github.io/scheduler/#/draganddrop

[image]

I also tried running this [maintained fork](https://github.com/hbatalhaStch/react-big-scheduler) but the issue still exists.

Then I tried adding `isDragging` as per [this GitHub issue in react-dnd](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/292#issuecomment-144781478) in `src\DnDSource.js` but then the scroll never 'finished': i.e., it was always returning true

```js
isDragging: (props, monitor) => {
                const item = this.resolveDragObjFunc(props);
                const draggedItem = monitor.getItem();

                return item.id === draggedItem.id && item.resourceId === draggedItem.resourceId;
            }
```

Comment: Please add a [mre] so we can try to reproduce this without to much trouble.

Comment: Seems to be a bug: https://github.com/StephenChou1017/react-big-scheduler/issues/253
You want us to fix ;)